# onChange select tag react js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to select values in drop down select tag in react, please help to achieve as below.

Here is my code

```
        <div>
          <SelectField
            label={"Select Job Category"}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target);
            }}
            value={listJobCategories}
            data={listJobCategories?.map((v) => (
              <option
                key={v.id}
                value={v}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  console.log(v);
                  console.log(e);
                }}
              >
                {v?.attributes?.Name}
              </option>
            ))}
          />

          {listCategories && (
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-1 space-x-2 mt-4 mb-6">
              {listCategories?.map((v) => (
                <Badge
                  title={v?.id}
                  className="text-white p-2"
                  key={v?.id}
                  isDeleteOn={true}
                  onClickDelete={() => {
                    console.log(v?.id);
                    // setListCategoriesId((prev) =>
                    //   prev.filter((el) => el != v?.id)
                    // );
                    // setListCategories((prev) =>
                    //   prev.filter(
                    //     (el) => el?.attributes?.Name != v?.attributes?.Name
                    //   )
                    // );
                  }}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
```

listJobCategories is useState from api, and the data structure looks like below:

```
{
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "Name": "Accounting & Finance",
                "createdAt": "2022-09-08T04:40:53.307Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-11-21T14:48:49.994Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-09-08T04:40:54.154Z",
                "Type": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
                "Name": "Corporate Affairs & Legal",
                "createdAt": "2022-09-08T04:41:25.968Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-11-21T14:51:53.205Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-09-08T04:41:26.822Z",
                "Type": null
            }
        }
}
```

This is how the UI looks like

[image]

I'm expecting to achieve like below

[image]

I have console log e.target, result as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the select value using `e?.currentTarget.value` that would contain your selected value!

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution

- Store selected categories in a new list
- map though selected list
- delete tag should remove from selected list

  ```
  // store selected categories
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);

   <div>
          <SelectField
            label={"Select Job Category"}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target);
              // Does this get id of single selection option or multiple
              // assuming single select mode
              const selectedId = // e.target.value ??
              const isAlreadySelected = selectedCategories?.find(i => i.id === selectedId)
              if (isAlreadySelected) {
                  // do you want to remove if selected again
                  // if yes remove from selected item and return
              } else {
                  // add an entry { key, label } 
                  const itemFromList = listJobCategories.find(i => i.id === selectedId)
                  setSelectedCategories(items => ({ ...items, { id: selectedItemId, label: itemFromList.attributes.name }})
              }
            }}
            value={listJobCategories}
            data={listJobCategories?.map((v) => (
              <option
                key={v.id}
                value={v.id}
              >
                {v?.attributes?.Name}
              </option>
            ))}
          />
          // loop through selected options
          {!!selectedCategories?.length && (
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-1 space-x-2 mt-4 mb-6">
              {selectedCategories?.map((v) => (
                <Badge
                  title={v?.id}
                  className="text-white p-2"
                  key={v?.id}
                  isDeleteOn={true}
                  onClickDelete={() => {
                    console.log(v?.id);
                    // delete from selected items, not the options of select
                    setSelectedCategories(prev => prev.filter(el => e.id !== v.id))

                  }}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
  ```

Hope this helps you in some way, if you want the exact solution, please create some minimal reproducable example